# How do I customize or replace the default landing page (servlet page) for IBM traveler?

Tags: ibm, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

When a user accesses https:/// and is redirected to https:///traveler after providing a correct username and password, They are presented with a basic information page showing their user status. There are also some links to get the IBM verse application, and manage their notes ID/devices.

I'd like to replace this page with a custom-written one, or at least remove some of the information from the page. e.g. full username, device information, sync activity, software and server hardware information, etc...

Can someone point me towards some documentation explaining if this is possible, or otherwise tell me how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This landing page is dynamically generated by the traveler servlet. The servlet can be found in `Domino-program-directory\Travler\lib`- Directory.

It is a java- archive called `traveler.jar`. 
You can try to "reverse engineer" that, but as the code is only there as compiled class- files, I do not see much of a chance to do this.

The only thing "readable" I could find (at a fast glance) was the properties- files defining the text- elements on that page.

If you really want to go that way, I would build an (XPage)- application (e.g. traveleruser.nsf), that gets the information from the servlet using an ajax- request in the background and then applies some style sheets / formatting to the response before presenting it to the user.

That's the closest you can get to customizing this page.